# Apache reverse-proxy changes the url in the browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

Below is my configuration:

All HTTPS requests are redirected to port 8081 of apache

And in my configuration file of apache I am using below mentioned configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName www.servername.com
    ServerAlias servername.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

   <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*_url_=(.*)
      RewriteRule ^.*$ /make?url=%1 [B,L,P,S=1]

  </Directory>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /make http://localhost:8084/
 ProxyPassReverse /make http://localhost:8084/

  </VirtualHost>
```

In which one more server is hosted on port 8084 which returns back the page.

Everything is working fine, apart from the url getting changed.

So if I am making a request as
[https://www.servername.com?*url*=queryString](https://www.servername.com?_url_=queryString)

it returns the correct response as expected, **but the url changes to**

https://www.servername.com/make?url=queryString

Please help me in figuring out, that what parameter I am missing in my apache configuration in the proxy, which can help in avoiding the url getting changed.

Thanks

Comment: 1. you doubled your logic: frist you use the `P`flag inside the `RewriteRule`, but then you _additionally_ define a ReverseProxy for that rewritten URL. _Why_ ? Why not directly rewrite to the second backend server in the `RewriteRule`? 2. What is the `RewriteBase` doing in the host definition? It only makes sense in `.htaccess` style files with their relative paths. I am surprised this does not raise an error, actually. 3. what is the `S=1` skip rule doing in there? There _is not rule to be skipped_ !

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think putting P in the mod rewrite was the issue. removing it. It worked fine. Also I have removed the skip as well.